# How to avoid HibernateException when merging detached entity with detached children in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's start with the following entities:

**ChildA**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child_a")
public class ChildA implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

  // ... Some specific columns

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent", nullable = false)
  @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
  private Parent parent;

  public Parent getParent() {
    return this.parent;
  }

  public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
}
```

**ChildB**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child_b")
public class ChildB implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

  // ... Some specific columns

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_parent", nullable = false)
  @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
  private Parent parent;

  public Parent getParent() {
    return this.parent;
  }

  public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
  }
}
```

**Parent**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idParent;

  // ... Some specific columns

  // This set with orphanRemoval = true
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<ChildA> childrenA;

  // This set with orphanRemoval = false
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<ChildB> childrenB;

  // ... Setters and getters for other columns

  public Set<ChildA> getChildrenA() {
    return this.childrenA;
  }

  public void setChildrenA(Set<ChildA> childrenA) {
    if (this.childrenA == null) {
      this.childrenA = childrenA;
    } else {
      this.childrenA.clear();
      this.childrenA.addAll(childrenA);
    }
  }

  public Set<ChildB> getChildrenB() {
    return this.childrenB;
  }

  public void setChildrenB(Set<ChildB> childrenB) {
    if (this.childrenB == null) {
      this.childrenB = childrenB;
    } else {
      this.childrenB.clear();
      this.childrenB.addAll(childrenB);
    }
  }
}
```

This is only an example of the kind of entities I'm dealing with. These entities are loaded, converted into equivalent DTOs, and displayed in a UI. In this UI, it is possible to add, modify or remove `ChildA` DTOs. `ChildB` DTOs can only be modified. Saving converts the `Parent` DTO and its set of children into a detached entity, that will be merged when `Parent` repository `save()` method is called. As I mentioned in the header, I'm using JPA.

All entities can be saved properly if children are added, deleted or modified. However, there is one case where saving process fails. In that situation, a `ChildA` entity must be deleted from its parent. When it saves, Hibernate throws the following exception: `org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: Parent.childrenA`.

I noticed that when Hibernate fails, the query launched by the entity manager to fetch the `Parent` will look like this:

```
select
    parent_.id_parent as id_parent1_93_1_,
    ...
    child_b_.id ad id_child_b4_66_,
    ...
from
    parent parent0_
left outer join
    child_b child_b1_
        on parent0_.id_parent=child_b1_­.id_parent
where
    parent0_.id_parent=?
```

For every other similar entities, the query will join `Parent` and `ChildA` instead.

```
select
    parent_.id_parent as id_parent1_93_1_,
    ...
    child_a_.id ad id_child_a4_66_,
    ...
from
    parent parent0_
left outer join
    child_a child_a1_
        on parent0_.id_parent=child_a1_­.id_parent
where
    parent0_.id_parent=?
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here? Why would Hibernate join `Parent` and `ChildA` in one case, and `Parent` and `ChildB` in the other? Is there a way to make Hibernate fetching a `Parent` joined with both `ChildA` and `ChildB` tables?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Update, 2020-06-04**

Let's define the following entities:

**ParentA**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_a")
public class ParentA implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idParent;

  // ... Some specific columns

  // Daughter set with orphanRemoval = true
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<ChildA> daughters;

  // Son set with orphanRemoval = false
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<ChildB> sons;

  // ... Setters and getters skipped
}
```

**ParentB**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent_b")
public class ParentB implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idParent;

  // ... Some specific columns

  // Daughter set with orphanRemoval = false
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<ChildA> daughters;

  // Son set with orphanRemoval = true
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Set<ChildB> sons;

  // ... Setters and getters skipped
}
```

As you can see, `ParentA` and `ParentB` are almost the same, except for the set with `orphanRemoval = true`. I've just made a test. From what I've observed, `ParentA` will be saved easily, while `ParentB` won't and will throw an `HibernateException`. When building its fetch query during merge process, it seems that Hibernate will join the first `Set` that appears in alphabetical order.

In both `ParentA` and `ParentB`, the `ChildA` table associated with the daughters will be joined in Hibernate query. In `ParentA`, the `daughters` set is the one with `orphan-removal = true`. Including its table in the `join` with its parent works. The `sons` are loaded individually after the `ParentA` fetch during merge, and are compared easily. In `ParentB`, since the `sons` set is the one with `orphan-removal = true` and the `ChildB` table is not joined, the problem occurs.

Any hints or explanations? Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you adding your detached `ChildA` instance to `childrenA` in `Parent` before merging? And I think the last class name should be `Parent`

Comment: @MinarMahmud Yes, detached `ChildA` and `ChildB` instances are added  to `childrenA` and `childrenB` in `Parent` before merging. And thanks for your last remark. I modified the `Parent` class name.